# Segmentation fault with gcc 7 and not with gcc 10?

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, g++

I am trying to compile the code with gcc 7 where build fails intermittently with issue :-

```
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program /home/comp/gcc-work/test/lib/ld-linux.so.2)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
```

I saw some of the gcc related forums over internet where it might cause because of using older gcc version and upgrading to gcc 10 might help. So i try to upgrade gcc version from gcc7 to gcc 10. I fired build multiple times and noticed there is no single instance of build failure with 'Segmentation fault'.

My doubt is :- If there is really an issue with existing GCC (i.e gcc7) toolchain, Build has to fail for all runs right? Why there is inconsistent behavior?

Note:- build should not run on same machine all the time. Our infrastructure should pick random machine out of pool. I am not able to find exact root cause whether the failure is because of hardware or tool chain.

Comment: `If there is really an issue with existing GCC (i.e gcc7) toolchain, Build has to fail for all runs right?` No, like with any C program, undefined behavior may be inconsistent.

Comment: @KamilCuk, So is it not related to memory/hardware related issue?  Definitely related to compiler toolchain side?

Comment: `internal compiler error` means that there is a problem with the compiler _program_, not your program. But like any other program on your machine, any program will fail when _you_ have a machine with faulty memory.

Comment: @KamilCuk, So in this case do you think probability of issue is more with compiler program (g++)  and not with faulty memory ?

Comment: These issues can have equal probability. Try to find possible GCC bug, you need to get a backtrace of crashed GCC process for that. Do a memory test with say Memtest86+ https://www.memtest.org/.

Answer (score 1):

> If there is really an issue with existing GCC (i.e gcc7) toolchain,

*Any* `internal compiler error:` *always* means that there *is* an issue with the toolchain -- it tells you *right there*.<sup>1</sup>

> Build has to fail for all runs right? Why there is inconsistent behavior?

Not true. There are *lots* of bugs which manifest as *intermittent* failure.

Some examples:

- heap use after free (the program may or may not crash depending on whether the `free`d memory has been overwritten)
- using uninitialized pointer (the program may or may not crash depending on whether the uninitialized memory happens to be zero).

---

<sup>1</sup> I suppose some `internal compiler error`s could be triggered by faulty memory and not a bug in the compiler itself, but then these failures should be limited to a single host.

Comment: @kathy It could be bug OR hardware issue. But if it happens on multiple hosts, then it's likely a bug. On the other hand, if the crash happens only on one host, then it's likely a HW issue on that particular host.

Comment: @kathy. No, a bug in GCC does _not_ have to manifest itself every time. It can be intermittent, as explained in the answer.

Comment: @Empliyed Russian, Thanks for your response.  So lets say there is a bug in gcc 7 causing the failure, Can we assume it got fixed on gcc 10 where there is no single instance of failure?

Comment: @kathy If you don't see any failures from GCC-10, then either the bug was fixed (which is likely), or it became exceedingly more rare. There is little practical difference between these two.